# Geb: Warn when a page takes longer than expected - Test Context in Page Object

Tags: wait, onload, pageload, geb

We want to add some type of functionality that when a page takes longer than x seconds to load a warning is presented.  We don't want that to throw a WaitTimeoutException, because the test can still execute cleanly, just longer than desired.  We would still use the default timeout to throw our WaitTimeoutException after 20 seconds.  This implies that x is less than 20.  It's essentially a performance check on the page itself.

I've tried using the onLoad function:

```
void onLoad(Page previousPage) {
    double warnSeconds = 0.001
    LocalDateTime warnTime = LocalDateTime.now().plusMillis((int)(warnSeconds * 1000))
    boolean warned = false
    boolean pageReady = false

    while(!warned && !pageReady) {
        if(LocalDateTime.now() > warnTime) {
            log.warn("${this.class.simpleName} took longer than ${warnSeconds} seconds to load")
            warned = true
        }
        pageReady = js.exec('return document.readyState') == 'complete'
    }
}
```

However:

> "Sets this browser's page to be the given page, which has already been
>   initialised with this browser instance."

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

**______________________________________EDIT_______________________________________**

Instead of using my own timer, used javascript `window.performance`.  Now I'm looking to be able to access a variable in my test from my pages.

**______________________________________EDIT_______________________________________**

```
void onLoad(Page previousPage) {
    def performance
    //TODO system property page time
    def pageTime = 8000

    if (browser.driver instanceof InternetExplorerDriver) {
        performance = js.exec('return JSON.stringify(window.performance.toJSON());')
    } else {
        performance = js.exec('return window.performance || window.webkitPerformance || window.mozPerformance ' +
                '|| window.msPerformance;')
    }

    int time = performance['timing']['loadEventEnd'] - performance['timing']['fetchStart']

    if (time > pageTime) {
        String errorMessage = "${this.class.simpleName} took longer than ${pageTime} milliseconds " +
                "to load. Took ${time} milliseconds."
        log.error(errorMessage)
        //TODO Soft Assert
    }
}
```

New chunk of code to actually get the correct performance data instead of using my own timer.  Now where I have //TODO Soft Assert, I have an object in my test that I want to access from my Page Object, but have no context.  How can I get context?